# HTML, CSS border collapse left side

Tags: html, css

I have div at the bottom of another element, it is set to

```
.div {
   display:none; 
}
```

until the screen width is below a certain amount. Then I use

```
@media(max-width:805px){
  .div {
     display:initial;
  }
```

than I have what the image shows. I do not understand what is going on.[image showcasing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M5jk.png)

I do not know what is the problem and probably have spent an hour trying to figure it out. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: if it's just html & css, it will be easier to help you if you provide an example instead of image [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. CSS is meaningless without HTML. Put it all in a snippet demo using the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  @media(max-width:805px){
   .div {
     display: block;
    }
```